# Python TCP Server using select() dealing with Error 110

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, timeout, connection

The Python TCP server based on select() works well. Here [TCP Server soruce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263904/python-tcp-server-using-select) you will find the code.

However, if connections are interrupted, the socket remains in place on the server side until a timeout (Errno 110) occurs and causes the server to crash.

- Why is this exception not intercepted by select()?
- Is there a standard procedure to avoid this error?

I am thinking of creating a watchdog thread for each connection with a timer. Any socket action would reset the timer. If the timer overflows after x seconds, the socket would be closed.

But is this the right/simplest way?

Comment: When `select` (at least `select.epoll`) will treat a disconnect as the client sending empty data, or you can use one of the other signals other than `EPILLIN`. Should be some equivilant of `select`. But the disconnect is a event, you just have to treat it as such, you should absolutely not use threads to solve this problem, since select is used specifically on non-threaded systems, where threads are not possible. And it's more than capable of solving the problem without threads being involved.

Comment: Normal disconnetions are detected as such and the clients are removed cleanly. 

Errno 110 is fired some times after a client is switched off/lost contact and no "normal" disconnect is sent. In our case a clientis can be mobile device that does not always have access to the internet.

Comment: Here is the error message from the console:

waiting for the next event
output queue for ('x.x.x.x', 13417) is empty

waiting for the next event
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "echo_server4.py", line 64, in <module>
        data = s.recv(1024)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Comment: I would like to give my question a more specific one. 
Why aren't all exeptions passed through --  readable, writable, exceptional = select. select (inputs, outputs, inputs) --  to the exceptional handler?